# All blog data on a page using custom query gives 404 for page 2 and onward

Tags: wp-query, pages

Below is my code on `page_{slug}.php`. The first page is working fine, but after 1 page, I am getting 404 error for all pages. Pagination with the main query is working fine, but it does not support custom query. Please help.

```
<?php
            $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $per_page = '2';
            $testimonial_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'blog_post',
                'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
                'paged' => $current_page,
            );
            $testimonials = new WP_Query($testimonial_args);
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($wp_query);die;
            ?>
            <?php if ($testimonials->have_posts()) : $i = 1; ?>
                <?php while ($testimonials->have_posts()) : $testimonials->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                        <div class="testimonial-card">

                            <div class="headline">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                                <span><?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <?php $i+=1; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <div class="pagination">
                    <?php                    
                        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely intege

                        echo paginate_links( array(
                            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%.html', esc_url( home_url( '/<slug>/page/' . $big ) ) ),
                            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                            'total' => 6
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php else : ?>

                <h2 class="center">Testimonials Not Found</h2>
                <p class="center">Sorry, but there are no testimonials, check back later!</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe this doesn't answer the question, but you really should change that `'total' => 6` to `'total' => $testimonials->max_num_pages`.

Comment: checked with that too not working

Comment: Pagination on blog and blog category page is working fine, issue is when i use custom wp-query its getting 404

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought you're using the code in the question on a Page (a post of the type `page`), but if you are actually using that code on an *archive-based page* (e.g. the home page, a category page, etc.), then the `404` error is normal. You can't paginate secondary/custom query on archive-based pages. Well, not when using the default `paged` *query string* in the URL.

So a possible solution is use a Page and make your custom loop in there — basically, the code in the question would work after you made the changes I mentioned in the original answer. I.e.:

1. Change the `base` argument in your `paginate_links()` call:

   ```php
   // change from this
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%.html', esc_url( home_url( '/<slug>/page/' . $big ) ) )
   // to this
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) )
   ```
2. And in addition to that `base`, you also need to change the `'total' => 6` to `'total' => $testimonials->max_num_pages`. (more details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#comment-418))

But if you actually wanted to customize the main query, then use the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts).

So for example, if your home page is set to show the *latest posts*, but you want to include only posts of the type `blog_post`, then you can simply add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'blog_post' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    }
} );
```

And that's really all you need. I.e. No need to worry about the pagination because a good theme always includes a working pagination for the main query on the home page and other archive-based pages.

Comment: thanks for your answer. problem is not because of pagination problem is a problem is related to custom query. when I use main query for looping pagination working fine but in case of WP_Query its checking data with main query and gets 404.

Comment: Have you already tried the code in the answer? And even if it doesn't answer the question, you are not actually properly using `paginate_links()`.

Comment: see https://ideone.com/9fCLET I want this with custom query not the main query

Comment: If you have a new code (that's relevant to the question), please add it to your question so that others can see the code without going to this comments section. And let me know if the revised answer helps and/or if you need further clarification on the answer.

Comment: Also, if you're indeed using your code on a custom page, e.g. `https://example.com/my-page/`, then if you still get the `404` error even after you have fixed the pagination arguments, it's probably because a plugin is not properly filtering the main query, so try disabling plugins and/or switching to a default theme.

Comment: yes I think there is a plugin that filter and cause 404

Comment: Well then, you'll need to find that on your own and perhaps you should write an answer later. But one way to confirm that, is add `'suppress_filters' => true` to your `WP_Query` args. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks, Sally Cj